# A seemingly random selection of apps keep crashing

Tags: applications, google-play-store, samsung, crashes

Starting from today, some apps on my phone just kept crashing.
At first it was mostly Google-related apps, and since I've had issues with Google Play services crashing before, I took the usual route of deleting app data and uninstalling updates. However, the issues persisted, and spread to other apps. Google kept crashing, the stock e-mail app kept crashing,my third party SMS app kept crashing...
Some apps crash when I open them, some don't. For some the problem is solved by uninstalling and reinstalling them, for some it isn't. Google-based apps like YouTube and Play Store work fine, but others like Chrome don't.
I can't seem to find a single "triggering" event that could have started this, apart from maybe some background update.
I am running Android 8.1.0 on a Samsung Galaxy J7(2016).

Is there any way to solve this ?

EDIT : I found the common factor between all those apps : they all store data on my SD card, which is still accessible but awfully slow. I'm guessing this is the root of the issue. However, I didn't specifically chose for those apps to be stored on the SD card, it seems Android automatically offloaded data there, and I don't know how to reverse it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out **uninstalling and reinstalling Google Chrome**, specifically, solved everything. As in, it stopped other apps from crashing as well. No idea why.
I initially tried transferring everything from my old SD card to a new one, but it didn't solve the problem. This did. Go figure.

Comment: Chrome can be set as the WebView implementation on at least some versions of Android, under System -> Developer Options. May be why this fixed it.